# Why did Rush do what he did at the end of SG-U S02E12?

Tags: stargate, stargate-universe

I just watched episode 12 in the latest season of *Stargate: Universe* but I don't understand it.

Of course the writers needed

> the second Rush to die because it would complicate the rest of the episodes, but why did they decide to write him out this way? 
>  
>  Rush sits in the chair maybe half a minute before Destiny goes down into the star. Why does he do that? Does he want to learn the knowledge of the ancients right before he dies? Why didn't he just come back to the original Destiny and do it there? (Then he could've helped them.) And if he was afraid they were going to punish him for accidentally killing the guy, wouldn't risking his life in the chair & learning a lot of stuff pay that off?

Answer (score 4):

He had nothing to lose, and he always wanted to gain the knowledge of the Ancients.  Also, they had the smoke descending around him right after he sat down, which caused the last guy who used the chair to vanish and later show up in Rush's visions.  I think the writers put him in the chair so if they want to bring an omniscient Rush back later on, they now can.

Comment: Franklin didn't become "omnisient"; he was essentially absorbed into the ship. Rush's visions were telepathic projections by the ship. There's no reason to believe that the older Rush could ever return since the older Destiny was destroyed moments thereafter.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I always had the pet theory that Franklin wigged out and essentially faked his death in the immediate aftermath of the download. Even if the library was smaller it was probably a rougher ride leaving him like a wild animal acting with unconscious knowledge of the ship. At least some of those interactions could've been real life Franklin in lucid moments before slipping away literally (through hatches and panels only he knows) and figuratively. I'd bet that Lady Rush talked to "online" looking for the master code was a full blown ascended ancient on the sly.

Answer (score 3):

Not too different from Keen. Killing Telford he figured meant he was in such big doo-doo. Also he might well have figured the universe wouldn't allow duplicates (of people) to live long anyway. Note how both human duplicates are eliminated by the end of the episode. Probably a sort of "moral" calculus on the part of the writers, who don't want to allow this sort of cloning.

So given his suspicion that he didn't have long to live, why not do something he wanted to experience, but that was just too risky to try. Plus, do these chair people really die, or are they moved to some other plane of existence. Stargate does contain the "religion" of ascension, and that might be the result of dying in the chair.

Comment: Who waS the first clone then? I thought Rush came alone in the Shuttle?

Comment: Telford from the first timeline still exists in the current timeline.

Comment: Yes. Thats what I meant, we ended up with duplicates of both Telford, and Rush, and both were killed off. The producers probably think the universe has some sort of rule that duplicates can not live more than 24hours.

Comment: Except the ancients didn't have a reliable "Ascension machine" even at the height of their power, the one in atlantis was very risky. It seems highly unlikely they built one, sent it out on a ship, then forgot about it for the next million years.

Comment: I'm betting on a last ditch attempt to upload himself and possibly transmit himself to the surviving Destiny, a long shot to be sure.  Or else he knew himself enough to know that if he hung around long enough both of them would try and kill the other out of frustration. ;P

Comment: Also SG1 (S3E6-Point of View) and Atlantis established that 2 of the same person existing in the same timeline causes problems and eventual destruction of the out of place person.

Comment: It was established that Franklin was "absorbed" by the computer. No ethereal magic here.

Comment: Given the Novus colony episodes, the universe doesn't seem to mind two of the same person existing (though separated by 2000 years).

Comment: @TysonoftheNorthwest Actually Atlantis didn't touch on the Entropic Cascade Failure problem, and a season ten episode of SG1 showed that it's not always in play, particularly when realities are close together. Since the realities in Twin Destinies had literally only just diverged (and were thus about as close as you can possibly get) I doubt that Entropic Cascade Failure would be relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

Budget. 
Cloning shots are expensive, and tricky to shoot.
They could not keep that up for more than one episode.

Comment: Got a reference for that as the actual reason?  It doesn't seem like it would cost _that_ much, considering the rest of the setting...  And there's a myriad of tricks to keep both characters without the cost, like with comms, or having them in separate parts of the ship.

Comment: Fringe did this for the better part of a season.